# Return MYSQL query result via JSON array/object?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table that contains a list of countries, i'm selecting all the countries from the table using

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM countries");
```

I now need to turn this result into a JSON array/object for use in my android application, however i can only get it to return the last country from the table.

How would i go about turning the entire result/list of countries into JSON to be used in my application?

```
$response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

        $response["country"] = $row;

    }



echo json_encode ( $response );
```

Comment: `$response["country"] = $row;` should be `$response["country"][] = $row;`

Comment: Good god. When will people _finally_ start reading the documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you or a future reader is still not sure *why* what you were doing wasn't working, when you use the following code in your `while` loop:

```
$response["country"] = $row;
```

in the first iteration of the loop, the `$response` array is created, with one key (`"country"`), and the value of `$row` is assigned to that key. With each subsequent iteration, the `"country"` key is *overwritten* with the new value of `$row`. That's why you end up with only the last country.

When you change it to

```
$response["country"][] = $row;
```

as a couple of people suggested, you assign an array to the `"country"` key and append the value of `$row` to it, and with each subsequent iteration, the new value of `$row` is *appended* to that array, so at the end of the loop, you'll have all of the countries.

The `fetchAll()` method is a shortcut that precludes the need for fetching rows in a loop. It does come with some caveats that you can read about in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), but if your result set is not too large and you're just going to `json_encode` and output it directly as you're doing here, it is a logical choice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) like

```
$response = array();
$response['country'] = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{

    $response["country"][] = $row;

}



echo json_encode ( $response );
```

Comment: Working, but inefficient.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `$response["country"] = $row;` all `$row` data every loop new initialize in `$response` variable. so if when you return `$response` array you can get last data.

So, Please follow bellow code

```
$response = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $response["country"][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode ( $response );
```

if you thinks you not use while loop then you can also bellow code

```
$response = array();
$response['country'] = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($response);
```